# Test @EventListener with custom events Spring Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, events, event-listener, spring-test

I have created a set of custom events for my application

```
sealed class myEvent(open val id: Int) {
  data class myBigEvent(override val id : Int) : myEvent(id)
  data class myIntermediateEvent(override val id: Int): myEvent(id)
}
```

I have a service that has a method for listening my custom events

```
@Service
class MailService(
  private val otherService: OtherService
) {

  @EventListener(myEvent.myBigEvent::class, myEvent.myIntermediateEvent::class)
  @Async
  fun handleProcessEvent(event: myEvent) {
    if (event.id != 10 && otherService.hasCompleted) {
      sendMail(event)
    }
  }
```

The interesting point is that IntellIj annotates with the eventlistener icon next to the method defintion. When clicking on it I get redirected to all my invocations of `publisher.publishEvent(myBigEvent)` or `publisher.publishEvent(myIntermediateEvent)`

The issue is when I try to test it. I have the following setup

```
@TestExecutionListeners
class myEventTest {

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var publisher: ApplicationEventPublisher

  @Mock
  private lateinit var mailService: MailService

  @BeforeClass
  fun start() {
    publisher = ApplicationEventPublisher {}
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
  }

  @Test
  fun `should receive cmlaProcessEvent published event`() {
    val cmlaProcessEvent = JobProcessEvent.CmlaProcessSimulationProcessEvent(mlaSimulationRun)
    this.publisher.publishEvent(cmlaProcessEvent)
    verify(mailService, times(1)).handleProcessEvent(cmlaProcessEvent)
  }
}
```

I get 'Wanted but not invoked' ... 'Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.'
I think my issue is with the ApplicationEventPublisher that is not sending the events to my MailService under this test context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@TestExecutionListeners`, since the default listeners should suffice.

If you're using Spring Boot, you should use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`.

In any case, you have to actually instruct JUnit to use Spring's testing support.

I assume that you are using JUnit 4, since I see `@BeforeClass` in the example. So I'm basing the following on that assumption (and using Java syntax instead of Kotlin).

You can instruct JUnit 4 to use Spring's testing support via `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Note, however, that you'll also need to specify where your `ApplicationContext` configuration is.

For Spring Framework, you can do that with `@ContextConfiguration`. For Spring Boot, you'll likely want to use `@SpringBootTest`. Consult the documentation for testing support in [Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing) and [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications) for details.

As a side note, you can also test `ApplicationEvent` publication without using a mock by using Spring Framework's built-in [testing support for application events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-application-events).

Comment: The @ContextConfiguration is loading the default Spring settings. So whenever I run the test with that annotation I still have the error of applicationContext not initialized. Could you provide an example ?

Comment: I added links to the testing documentation for Spring Framework and Spring Boot. The official reference docs provide basic information. You can also find numerous tutorials, blogs, and books on the subjects.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I worked it out ;) 
Continuing my path to master Spring Framework!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. Have fun learning Spring!